# RREF of matrix credibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I've been given an assignment and there is always the emphasise to prove everything, not just find the answer.

Now in this case, we're given a matrix, A, defined in R^3,  of which we need to find the basis of the col(A), then give the dim col(A) [should be written as dim(A)]. Then we are asked for the row(A), then give the dim row(A) [should be written rank(A)]. Finally, the null(A) and then following is find the nullity dim null(A) [again should be written simply as the nullity(A)].

Super simple to work out... But what am I missing here??

Is it not suffice to just find RREF(A) and simply extract the pivot columns, pivot rows and by definition find the dim(A) and rank(A)??

I can use some theorem to show that nullity(A) = n - rank(A), where n represents the number of columns I have in A.

Which in this case alone shows nullity(A) = 1, and we're working in R^3, so I can just find the cross product of my basis vectors for the col(A).

Like relatively speaking this seems suspiciously easy compared to my last assignment. Would anyone know what I'm missing with my approach?

Comment: First a bit of notation confusion: both dim row(A) and dim col(A) are equal to rank(A).  Writing dim(A) as you did doesn't make sense.

Comment: column space is not necessarily preserved under row operations. so simply extracting the pivot columns wont work

Comment: Next, a question: do you know why finding pivot columns gives you col(A)?  Could you prove it?  If so, using the RREF method should be fine in any course.

Comment: @Alain Chau: the standard procedure I used to teach for col(A) uses RREF to find pivots, but then the _basis_ for the columnspace is the columns in $A$ that correspond to those with pivots in $RREF(A)$.  It looks like the OP learned this method.

Comment: @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman by some theorem that is, never the less, dim(A) and rank(A), ARE still defined separately.

Comment: @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman why I find pivot columns gives me col(A) is not fully understood. I mean, if I had to give an educated guess it'd be, when row reducing A to get R, for any x in R^(same as A's columns), Ax and Rx still give the same solution set. I wouldn't know how to further explain though.

Comment: (about dim(A) ) Heh, that's strange.  Unfortunately people use a lot of different notation when teaching linear algebra.  Your proof is probably good, but really your teaching staff is there to give feedback on your style of writing proofs so it would be a good idea to take this to office hours to discuss what level of detail is needed.

Comment: Thanks @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman I've sent the Professor an email. I hope it works out.

Comment: Ah, so that's an important thing you should try to think through.  A hint would be that row operations do not affect the relationship between the columns of $A$.  Try an example of $A$ and how you would write the non-pivot columns of $RREF(A)$ in terms of the pivots.  Then look at the corresponding columns of $A$ and try adding them up in the same way; it should be consistent.